# PHP Unlimited file size upload

Tags: php

```
post_max_size = 0
upload_max_filesize = 0
```

(settings on php.ini)
Does it mean that users can upload to my website with unlimited file size ?

PHP 7.4.26, Apache 2.4.51 on WAMP server 3.2.6 (all are 64bit)

Comment: `unlimited file size` .... Question: if the size of the file exceeds the free space in your server, what happens ?

Comment: The webserver defines its own setting for max upload size.

Comment: I have around 20TB storage server and it is used for store video projects. I wonder if with that settings, we can ignore the limitation of size ?

Comment: For your case, you may also need to amend the following two ini settings: max_input_time , max_execution_time

Comment: Can you suggest the value for both settings, I do not know the best value for them.

Comment: Hint : normally uploading a file of moderately big size should take less than 10 minutes. (depends on the network speed) But you may further adjust.